# Why does BizTalk need MSDTC?

Tags: biztalk, msdtc

Has anyone come across a good explanation as to **why** MSDTC is required for a BizTalk server farm?

Thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 4):

Because everything is done in transaction and some parts of BizTalk are still native COM or COM+ components. MSDTC is prerequisite for installing BizTalk.

If you check your SQL Server you will see that there are several databases created for BizTalk. BizTalk is continuously moving data among these databases and uses distributed transactions for that.

Answer (score 2):

Also, when using the SQL Adapter to make SQL calls, BizTalk will enlist all calls in a distributed transaciton for ATOMICity.